# A finite dimensional subspace of a Banach space is complemented.

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show

> every finite dimensional subspace of a Banach space $X$ is complemented

by using this theorem

> suppose $X$ be a Banach space and $M$ be a closed subspace of $X$. $M$ is complemented if and only if exist continuous map $P:X\rightarrow X$ such that $Im(P)=M$ and $P^{2}=P$.

I know every finite dimensional subspace of a Banach space is closed. please help me to find $P$.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688454/does-every-finite-dimensional-subspace-of-any-normed-linear-space-have-a-closed) may help.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $Y=span\{y_{1},\ldots , y_{n}\}$. For all $j\in \{1,\ldots ,n\}$
define $g_{j}:Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\forall \, y\in Y \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,  g_{j}(y)=g_{j}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i}y_{i})=c_{j} .$$
then $g_{j}$ is linear and bounded function. Also
$$\forall \, j \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, g_{j}(y_{i})=\begin{cases}1 & i=j \\ 0 & i\neq j\end{cases}.$$
By Hann banach theorem extended all $g_{j}$ to $f_{j}\in X^{*}$ such that $f_{j}|_{Y}=g_{j}$. Define $P:X\rightarrow X$,
$$\forall x\in X \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, P(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_{i}(x)y_{i}.$$
Clearly, $P$ is continuous, $Im(P)=Y$ and $P^{2}=P$.